# How to tell what physical device clicked a button in C#?

Tags: c#, mouse, click, button, touchscreen

I have a Form with buttons. This application is meant to run on a touchscreen computer. When a button is clicked I would like to know whether it was clicked by the mouse or the touchscreen.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Which OS are you using? XP, Win7?

Comment: This sounds like a really poor choice in UI design

Answer (score 3):

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ((MouseEventArgs)e).Button.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        //If an exception is catch, it means the mouse was not used.
    }
}
```

This is a gross way to do it, because it will catch an exception anytime button is "clicked" by something else than the mouse, either touchscreen or keyboard's return. But it will do the job :)

Comment: There has to be a better, more direct way to do this.

Comment: @Stimul8d I couldn't have said it better.

Answer (score 1):

Taking from Wildhorn's answer this way avoids the exceptions being thrown:

```
MouseEventArgs thisObject = e as MouseEventArgs

if(thisObject != null)
{
//Do Something
}
```

It's not much different but you don't have the overhead of the exception handling. Also you could try multiple casts til you got the right one.

Comment: Much more elegant!